# Angular : Getting values of check box when it is checked

Tags: angularjs

This is my view I want to get the values such as diabetes , or htn etc cause I want to store them in a string format. But the way I am dooing it right now I get it in an object format

```
 font(color ='green', size ='3')
                 strong Past History
               .checkbox
                   label
                       input(type='checkbox', value='',name = 'diabetes', ng-model = 'formData.history.diabetes')
                       | DIABETES
               .checkbox
                   label
                       input(type='checkbox', value='',name = 'htn', ng-model = 'formData.history.htn')
                       | HTN
               .checkbox
                   label
                       input(type='checkbox', value='',name = 'asthma', ng-model = 'formData.history.asthma')
                       | ASTHMA/COPD
```

Now in my controllers when I

```
console.log($scope.formData.history)
```

I get an output like:

```
`{diabetes : true}`
```

But I want to send this data to my backend in a String form. Any idea how to get only "diabetes" or "htn" . thank you

Comment: If you want to send the data as JSON use JSON.stringify() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the value binded to the checkbox model is by default a boolean. That's why you get `true` or `false` as values.

Use the directives `ng-true-value` and/or `ng-false-value` if you want to change that. Here is an example, in html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="htn" ng-model="formData.history.htn" ng-true-value="'htn'">
```

Answer (score 1):

By your scenario you should declare data-ng-model as **Array**.

Your answer is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/K6nk8prlz8gU5VNARfln?p=preview)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model='formData.history[1]' ng-true-value="'htn'">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 font(color ='green', size ='3')
                 strong Past History
               .checkbox
                   label
                       input(type='checkbox', value='', data-ng-true-value='diabetes', name = 'diabetes', ng-model = 'formData.history.diabetes')
                       | DIABETES
               .checkbox
                   label
                       input(type='checkbox', value='', data-ng-true-value='htn', name = 'htn', ng-model = 'formData.history.htn')
                       | HTN
               .checkbox
                   label
                       input(type='checkbox', value='', data-ng-true-value='asthma', name = 'asthma', ng-model = 'formData.history.asthma')
                       | ASTHMA/COPD
```

Check how I used `data-ng-true-value` attribute if checked that will contain the value. Similarly you can have `data-ng-false-value` when it is unchecked. That should give you `{diabetes : diabetes}, {htn: htn}` But the way you have written your ng-model it will act like radio button if you need multiple selection your ng-model need to be modified to fit the scenario. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify($scope.formData.history)
```

This should solve your problem if you want your data in a JSON format.